# Apigility DBconnected REST item not found on POST

Tags: php, post, laminas-api-tools

I have just settled up a  db connected service. I changed the Entity Identifier Name to match with my table, added three fields(one is the identifier) and put some length validation. No further changes, so far, so good, I can `get/`, `get/:id` with no problem.

The problem comes with the half post. doing **a post** does insert in the table but my response is **404 item not found**. When trying to post the same data I get a duplicated key error, of course.

I don't understand what's wrong with the not found after inserting. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE 3/9**

Reading some post and groups I could narrow the problem to `zf-apigility/src/DbConnectedResource.php`

```
public function create($data) {
    $data = $this->retrieveData($data);
    $this->table->insert($data);
    $id = $this->table->getLastInsertValue();
    return $this->fetch($id);
}
```

Since my db is mysql and my primary key is a String i belive `getLastInsertValue()` tries for an int id.

The solution i found was related to a postrgress db using features / sequence that apigility provided but i think there should be a simpler way to solve this. [Apigility - Features](https://apigility.org/documentation/recipes/customizing-table-gateway-with-features).

I am looking for an aproach to either specify the method to get the last inserted value confirmation or to inherit from DbConnectedResource.php and re implement the `create($data)` method.

I know this should be configured in the `API/config/module.config.php` under `service_manager` category but don't really know how.

Comment: you are missing the code for us to look at....

Comment: For displaying inline code fragments, use backquotes.

Comment: @Anthon thanks for editing, missed  a few english classes back there.